# How to fix Resource versus Resources error in Xamarin - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I have a very simple Xamarin Android app. It has a text box and a button. Here's the activity_main.axml file in Resources.Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView 
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
<Button
    android:text="Get Number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnAutoGenerate" />
```

In the Solution Explorer I have Assets and Resources.

Under Resources is layout and under layout is activity_main.axml

Not complex at all.

In MainActivity.cs, the OnCreate procedure is this:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TextView txtNumber;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        txtkNumber = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNumber);
        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAutoGenerate).Click += (o, e) =>
        txtNumber.Text = btnAutoGenerate_Click(o, e);

    }
```

I'm not sure where Resource is defined (as in the xml it's Resources) but even though at first this compiled with no problem now I get the error: the name "Resource" does not exist in the current context.

Because when the default files are first generated, it is

```
 SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
```

even though the "Resource.Layout" is pointing to Resources.layout. Not sure why.

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes. Also closed the project, closed VS and reopend. This has happened to a few of these starter projects. I do not know where Resource is defined as pointing to Resources. I also exited VS, deleted the bin and obj folders, restarted and rebuilt with the same error.

Comment: I started out fresh with a new app, added the textbox etc. and recompiled and it is OK. BUT, I am bothered by this strange error and worry it will reoccur down the line.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but you are trying to access resource.layout folder right?